# Python dataframe datetime based if and else condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a datatime dataframe. I want to compare it with a reference date and assign `before` it is less than and `after` if greater.
**My code:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(1.0,9.0)},index=pd.date_range(start='2020-05-04 08:00:00', freq='1d', periods=8))
df=     
                       A
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0
2020-05-05 08:00:00  2.0
2020-05-06 08:00:00  3.0
2020-05-07 08:00:00  4.0
2020-05-08 08:00:00  5.0
2020-05-09 08:00:00  6.0
2020-05-10 08:00:00  7.0
2020-05-11 08:00:00  8.0

ref_date = '2020-05-08'
```

**Expected answer**

```
df=     
                       A    Condi.
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0    Before
2020-05-05 08:00:00  2.0    Before
2020-05-06 08:00:00  3.0    Before
2020-05-07 08:00:00  4.0    Before
2020-05-08 08:00:00  5.0    After
2020-05-09 08:00:00  6.0    After
2020-05-10 08:00:00  7.0    After
2020-05-11 08:00:00  8.0    After
```

**My solution:**

```
df['Cond.'] = = ['After' if df.index>=(ref_date)=='True' else 'Before cleaning']
```

**Present answer**

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: `df.index>=(ref_date)=='True` no. First, boolean objects would be `True` not `'True'`, but you *never* need to use `== True`. Perhaps more importantly, you are creating a list with a single element, although, that is failing because you are doing the vectorized operation on `df.index` which creates a boolean array, hence the error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ref_date = "2020-05-08"

df["Cond"] = np.where(df.index < ref_date, "Before", "After")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                       A    Cond
2020-05-04 08:00:00  1.0  Before
2020-05-05 08:00:00  2.0  Before
2020-05-06 08:00:00  3.0  Before
2020-05-07 08:00:00  4.0  Before
2020-05-08 08:00:00  5.0   After
2020-05-09 08:00:00  6.0   After
2020-05-10 08:00:00  7.0   After
2020-05-11 08:00:00  8.0   After
```

Comment: Mine is a big df. For my original df, I got following error: `file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name IndexError: list index out of range` . I just did this `df.index < ref_date` and I got this `array([ True,  True, ... False, False])`. So, what could be wrong?

Comment: @Mainland With `df.index < ref_date` you get boolean array. Use this boolean array in `np.where()` to set "Before"/"After" as I have in my example.

Comment: @Mainland that doesn't make any sense. If you are getting an error, edit your question and post the full error message

Comment: I saved `blary = df.index <= ref_date` and `np.where(blary,'Before','After')`. This again gave same error. I am still surprised. No idea why.

Comment: Issue sorted. No more issues. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Helping you fix the list comprehension approach you took, you can use:

```
df['Cond'] = ['After' if x >= pd.to_datetime(ref_date) else 'Before' for x in df.index]
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I do not why but I am running into error `file = filename.replace("/", "\\").rsplit("\\", 1)[1] # find the file name IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Issue sorted. No more issues. Thanks